# How to fix network issues with LXD on Fedora 31?

Tags: fedora, lxd

Has anyone had success using LXD on Fedora 31? I have been using it on another machine with Fedora 30 just fine, but after installing Fedora 31 on a new laptop, the containers don't get an IPv4 address:

```
$ lxc list
WARNING: cgroup v2 is not fully supported yet, proceeding with partial confinement
+-------+---------+------+------+------------+-----------+
| NAME  |  STATE  | IPV4 | IPV6 |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+-------+---------+------+------+------------+-----------+
| c1    | RUNNING |      |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+-------+---------+------+------+------------+-----------+
```

Attempting something like ping inside the container gives the error:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Nothing works that needs the network, but otherwise the containers seem fine and the network is fine on the host laptop.

The one notable difference I see is the warning on Fedora 31:

```
WARNING: cgroup v2 is not fully supported yet, proceeding with partial confinement
```

The version of LXD is 3.18 on both machines (installed using snap), and I've compared with both environments but couldn't see any glaring differences that would point to a problem other the cgroup warning.

This is what the network bridge looks like:

```
$ lxc network show lxdbr0
WARNING: cgroup v2 is not fully supported yet, proceeding with partial confinement
config:
  ipv4.address: 10.192.103.1/24
  ipv4.nat: "true"
  ipv6.address: none
description: ""
name: lxdbr0
type: bridge
used_by:
- /1.0/containers/c1
managed: true
status: Created
locations:
- none
```

Any ideas on where to start looking?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/fedora/):

```
sudo grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix to the problem. Turns out that cgroup v2 warning was more than just a warning. If cgroup v2 is disabled, it works as expected.

To disable cgroup v2, add the following to the linux boot line:

```
systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0
```

There may be other ways to fix it, but this works for now.